# How to define member function in separate source file?

Tags: c++, function, definition, compilation

Consider following two programs.

**p1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
struct test
{
    void fun();
};
int main()
{
    test t;
    t.fun();
}
```

**p2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
void test::fun()
{
    std::cout<<"fun() is called\n";
}
```

I am compiling like following.

```
g++ -c -o p1.o p1.cpp
g++ -c -o p2.o p2.cpp   <--------- This gives me compiler error.
```

How can I solve this error? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to declare the class `test` (including its methods) in p2.cpp (usually, we declare it in a header file and include the header file in both sources files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to:

1. Create a new file test.h
2. Move your `struct test { ... };` into the file test.h
3. Add `#include "test.h" to both of your source files.
4. Recompile both files.

You may want to consider using a makefile to compile your files, and add a dependency on `test.h` to p1.cpp and p2.cpp, so that these get recompiled when you modify test.h